# Making workspaces clickable to start Eclipse on them?

Tags: windows, eclipse

We use a lot of workspaces, and frequently switch between them.  I was wondering if there is a trick that can allow me to simply click a workspace in Windows Explorer and have Eclipse started on it.

A "create shortcut for Eclipse" creator might also be interesting, but I was envisioning perhaps a special name for the workspace triggering this behaviour?

Suggestions?

(Edit:  I am aware of the --data switch, but I'm looking for the bridge to Windows Explorer which may use that switch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found a solution based on https://superuser.com/q/412312/7401, namely to craft a few registry entries, to get "Open Folder as Eclipse Project" to show up when right-clicking on a workspace.

[image: right click menu on workspace showing Open Folder as Eclipse Project]

"eclipse-folder.reg" looks like:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\eclipse]
@="Open Folder as &Eclipse Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\tra\\Downloads\\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\\eclipse\\eclipse.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\eclipse\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\tra\\Downloads\\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64\\eclipse\\eclipse.exe\" -data \"%1\""
```

Be very careful when editing to point at another location.  All backslashes must be doubled inside the string.  Works for me under Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Eclipse with a parameter do specify the workspace. I think it's `-data` - but check the documentation. So then you can just make a bunch of desktop shortcuts, one for each workspace.

Documentation can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at [Yoxos 5 Beta](http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/yoxos-5-beta/). It is said to provide the shortcut functionalities - on the other hand I have never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are under Windows. Just in case someone would have the same problem but under Linux environment, i had the same question and am using right now a simple shell script which behaves like an "eclipse workspace launcher". It shows me all my workspaces, with the number of projects contained in each workspaces. So i can easily launch one dedicated workspace.

My folder structure is just something like :

> ~/java/workspaces/eclipse/workspace1/project1/
>
> ~/java/workspaces/eclipse/workspace1/project2/
>
> ~/java/workspaces/eclipse/workspace2/project3/

and so on. This then gives something like :

[image]

The script only needs the Linux "[Zenity](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/2.32/zenity.html)" package (Gnome) and should run on any shell interpreter :

```
#!/bin/ksh

windows_title="Eclipse Launcher"
WNG_ICON="/opt/gnome/share/pixmaps/gnome-warning.png"
ECLIPSE_ICON="/opt/Eclipse_DEV/Eclipse-V3-2-1/icon.xpm"

WORKSPACES_DIR="<path_to_my_workspaces_directory>"
WORKSPACES=""
ls -1d "${WORKSPACES_DIR}"/* | while read ITEM
do
        WORKSPACE_NAME="$(basename ${ITEM})"
        WORKSPACE_COUNT=$(ls -1d "${ITEM}"/* 2>/dev/null | grep -v total | wc -l)
        WORKSPACES="${WORKSPACES}${WORKSPACE_NAME} ${WORKSPACE_COUNT} 
"
done

ret=`zenity --list --width="280" --height="410" --window-icon="${ECLIPSE_ICON}" \
--text "Choisissez le workspace" \
--column "Workspace" \
--column "Projets" \
$WORKSPACES --title "${windows_title}"`

if [[ ! -z $ret ]] ; then
        export JAVA_HOME="/<path_to_java_home>/"
        export GTL_MODULES="";
        cmd='<path_to_eclipse>/eclipse -showlocation -data "'${WORKSPACES_DIR}$ret'" -vm '${JAVA_HOME}'/bin/java -vmargs  -Xss4m -Xms256m -Xmx384m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
        eval $cmd
fi
```

Otherwise, as stated above, [Yoxos](http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/) seems indeed a good choice (i've just discovered recently about this project on my own).